# How to use system tray with X11 forwarding?

Tags: linux, debian, x11, xforwarding, headless

I'm using X11 forwarding to use GUI apps from my headless remote server. Everything was fine until I needed to use a program that needs system tray.

Program needs a system tray to work correctly otherwise GUI doesn't show up.

How can I run a GUI program that needs a system tray through X11 forwarding?

Comment: It's better -and faster- to use vnc.

Comment: @IporSircer  Is it possible to use VNC in a text mode only server, to run GUI programs installed in server side using local Xorg, via ssh remotely like we do in X11 forwarding?  For example installer assistants, and others?

Comment: It just works for me. What are you forwarding through? What do you have on the local end? I am forwarding with `ssh -X`, I am running kde plasma locally.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor how it works? it just appears on your local system tray? I'm connecting from a Windows machine to a remote linux machine.

Comment: So you need to run a system tray, it won't go into the MS system tray. Are you running an X11 window-manager, and desktop system (tray, task-bar, etc.)?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  How? Be more clear please I'm a newbie to linux. It's a headless server so no desktop system.

Comment: What X11 stuff are you running on your MS-Windows?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm just using MobaXterm. It has embedded X11 server.

Comment: MobaXterm is proprietary, and I don't know anything about it. If it lacks a tray, then you will have to run one separately or use a different tool.

Comment: I added to my answer, a bit about stalonetray.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put stuff in the tray, unless you have a tray.

The MS tray and the X11 tray are not the same: The MS tray can not hold X11 tray items.

Therefore you need to run an X11 tray.

On debian do `apt-get install stalonetray`. Then read the manual. It claims to be a stand-alone tray, so can be used if not running as system with a tray.

Comment: I may add more, if I get more info from OP

Comment: "Therefore you need to run an X11 tray." Yes, that's just what I'm trying to do. If you know how I can accomplish that, tell me please.

Comment: Well, installed stalonetray but can you tell me how will I use it please?

Comment: I have never used it. But assume that you have to run it. (it should then appear on your desktop)